# Appropriate EIP selection for sequential subflow calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In [Spring Integration](https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) I need to send a message sequentially to subflow A (it stores the message into DB) and then to subflow B (it uses some DB lookup). Whole A and B execution should be performed in the boundary of one transaction.

Initially, [Publish-Subscribe Channel](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html) with 2 subscribers for A and B in one thread was used. However, there are 2 drawbacks

1. there is no guaranteed order of subscribers execution
2. it's easy to add [`task-executor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel) attribute to the channel. Thus, A and B will be executed in parallel in different threads and, thus, in different transactions.

So, what [EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/) is better to use here?

I'm thinking about [Recipient List Router](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RecipientList.html) but, again, [can't see guaranty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter) of a message sending order for recipients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `order` attribute on the `AbstractMessageHandler` which guaranties how subscribers will be subscribed to the `PublishSubscribeChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-directchannel:

> The order is determined by an optional order value defined on the handlers themselves or, if no such value exists, the order in which the handlers are subscribed.
>
> If a certain situation requires that the dispatcher always try to invoke the first handler, then fallback in the same fixed order sequence every time an error occurs, no load-balancing strategy should be provided. In other words, the dispatcher still supports the failover boolean property even when no load-balancing is enabled. Without load-balancing, however, the invocation of handlers will always begin with the first according to their order. For example, this approach works well when there is a clear definition of primary, secondary, tertiary, and so on. When using the namespace support, the "order" attribute on any endpoint will determine that order.

Also source code of `AbstractDispatcher`:

```
private final OrderedAwareCopyOnWriteArraySet<MessageHandler> handlers =
        new OrderedAwareCopyOnWriteArraySet<MessageHandler>();
```

Also an `order` XML attribute description:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="order" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Specifies the order for invocation when this endpoint is connected as a
subscriber to a channel. This is particularly relevant when that channel
is using a "failover" dispatching strategy. It has no effect when this
endpoint itself is a Polling Consumer for a channel with a queue.

                ]]></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: Well... it'll help but is `PublishSubscribeChannel` appropriate EIP in my case at all? Is it possible to use `chain` e.g.?

Comment: If you need to maintain TX and order of services than no choice: single-thread publish-subscribe channel